# SSIS handling NULL and blank spaces

Tags: ssis

hello i am new to SSIS and iam receiving text file created by SSIS iam using wizard to load it to oracle table but in the text file there is columns contain the String NULL and other contain blank string instead of zero length column is there an auto way to make these value to become actual  null value in the table or do i have to create derived column for each one of theses cases

thank you,

Answer (score 13):

Within an SSIS project in the SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2015/SQL Server 2016, the way to address the handling of empty columns seems to be via a property of the Flat File Source component (not certain whether space-only columns qualify):

1. Right-click the Flat File Source and choose **Show Advanced Editor...**.
2. Select the **Component Properties** tab.
3. Set **RetainNulls** property to True (default is False).

[image: RetainNulls Property]

Comment: This was the definitive answer for my situation.  It should be noted that this correctly distinguishes between "data","","data" (empty string) and "data",,"data" (null field).

Comment: Note that this option is on the Flat File SOURCE, not the Flat File CONNECTION.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to convert the value into null if your input value in empty/blank, then you can try  (under assumption datatype is of string/varchar) :

```
LEN(TRIM([ColumnName]))==0 ? NULL(DT_WSTR, 10) : [ColumnName]
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue, you can use a script component and add the code below to loop through all the columns and replace each text null with actual null value...

```
foreach (PropertyInfo dataColumn in Row.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (dataColumn.Name.ToLower().EndsWith("_isnull") == false && dataColumn.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
            object objValue = dataColumn.GetValue(Row, null);

            if (objValue != null && objValue.ToString() == 'NULL')
            {
                 dataColumn.SetValue(Row, null, null);
            }
    }
}
```

Code explanation is **[here](http://waheedrous.wordpress.com/2014/02/24/ssis-global-replace-for-all-columns-using-a-script-component/)**

Answer (score 2):

If you're using SSIS 2008, there's also the Null Manager component from Tactek Data Systems. It isn't free, but it's pretty cheap - like $10 bucks. ([www.tactek.com](http://www.tactek.com)). You can convert empty strings to nulls, nulls to empty strings, and nulls to "filler" values like "Unknown" or "NA".

Answer (score -3):

I don't think there is any way to do this using the standard Flat File Source SSIS provides. To do this I make use of a custom component called Delimited File Source, which can be downloaded here: http://ssisdfs.codeplex.com/. As its name indicates, it's also much better at handling delimited files, plus it has the option of treating empty strings as NULL.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the clear answer but what about the string null how can make it as a NULL

Comment: I don't know how it will handle that, but you can always use a derived Derived Column Transformation to convert the "null" strings to a NULL value.