# How to handle the error while bulk insert empty string into not null column using SSIS

Tags: ssis

How to manage to insert empty string into not null column using SSIS bulk insert.

My Scenario is,

I have a data in text file which is tab delimited. some of the not null field values contains empty string. while i try to insert using SSIS, I got below error.

```
[OLE DB Destination [730]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Unspecified error".

[OLE DB Destination [730]] Error: There was an error with input column "Copy of UOM_CD" (3675) on input "OLE DB Destination Input" (743). The column status returned was: "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.".

[OLE DB Destination [730]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (743)" failed because error code 0xC020907D occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "OLE DB Destination Input" (743)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (730) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (743). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
```

How to solve this issue, Please give some help on this.

Comment: An empty string is different is not a NULL value. You can insert an empty string into a NULLABLE column without problems.

Comment: but, I am getting this error, while insert empty string into nullable column. any configuration issues?

Comment: This [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550964/ssis-handling-null-and-blank-spaces) might be useful to find a solution for this

Comment: The error you got back has nothing to do with NULLs per se. The error is "The value violated the integrity constraints for the column", which could mean a foreign key constraint, a check or unique constraint, a data type mismatch ... You need to do more homework to identify which row is causing your error. Redirect your error rows to a text file so you can see what's causing the issue.